# graphql vs direct transfer of sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, rest, graphql

I am trying to find the most efficient client server communication protocol. Rest API becomes too cumbersome at some point. Can graphql be more efficient than the client sending sql queries directly to the server. I am not looking for the security concerns(that aside), can someone throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing will *'be more efficient than the client sending sql queries directly to the server'* as any server is a layer over DB engine/server (with or w/o additional ORM abstraction layer) needing some processing (additional time/resources/processing costs) ...

... graphql is for flexible querying [query/get only what you need] data/relations without REST limits (mainly about deep relations, no need to predefine them, overfetching, etc.)

Comment: I just cannot see the benefits of graphql . Is it that sending SQL queries over the wire is boring that people are adding graphql...just to keep things interesting?

Comment: sending SQL has many CONS (solved by graphql layer): no one standard/syntax, no types interoperability (standards), deep relations etc. ... editing graphql query is much easier than constructiong sql query (joins/where/etc) ... and graphql can work (hide behind one endpoint) over many/misc services, not DBs only ... standarized high level abstraction layer